# Digital text disappeared of pdf in Latex. Why?

Tags: pdf, thesis

I am just trying to incroporate PDF into Latex by either using:

```
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{example.pdf}
```

OR

```
%\includegraphics[
 % page= 1,
  %width=\textwidth,
  %height=\textheight,
  %keepaspectratio,
  %trim=0 0 0 20pt,
%]{example.pdf}
```

The issue is that the person replied digitally to my questions on the pdf. (When opening it via Adobe or the Browser I can see his answers). But when incorporating it in LaTeX the text has disappeared. Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: no, I do not understand the answer of the link you posted

Comment: One recommendation is to figure out how to print from your preferred PDF viewer such that the comments are also shown.  Then just "Print to PDF" instead of sending the document to a printer.  Now include that new PDF in your Latex document.

Comment: I tried it. Opened the Adobe Reader, clicked Print, then saved it as PDF. It still does not work :(

Comment: Yeah, I too find this issue very frusterating. The comments made  on the pdf were stored on the annotation layer. Due to the way annotations are stored in the pdf format, they are difficlut for tools that inserts pages from a pdf document to properly display. Same issue happens if you have links in the pdf -- they will not be there when you extract pages from the document. For your purposes, you'll need to find a tool that flattens the annotation layer then things should work -- this will may make the coment difficlut to remove from that document though.